# WebView2 show html variable instead of url

Tags: c#, html, xaml, webbrowser-control, webview2

Hey guys I have a program that still uses the old WebBrowser Xaml control. Now I wanted to exchange this on WebView2 here I have problems. Currently, the body of an email is pulled from a database as html code and written to a variable, which is linked to the WebBrowser control.  Only WebView2 wants a URL to be passed in the source function. How can I pass a variable containing HTML code instead of a link to a web page? Or are there other alternatives for this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try [NavigateToString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.winforms.webview2.navigatetostring?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1343.22)

```
await webView21.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();
webView21.NavigateToString(anEmailHTMLVariable);
```